# Shortcut for echo “<pre>”;print_r($myarray) inside foreach laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Is there a shortcut for

```
echo "<pre>";
   print_r($Array);
```

inside a foreach loop using laravel?I did the following

```
@foreach ($getallDetials as $user)
  {{ print_r($user) }}
@endforeach
```

I get Output like

```
[sname] => sdsds [course] => 10 [no] => sdsd [number] => 1 ) 1 stdClass Object ( [s_no] => 2 [sname] => asasa [course] => asas [no] => asasas [number] => 1 ) 1 stdClass Object ( [s_no] => 3 [sname] => asasa [course] => asas [no] => sasa [number] => 2 )
```

But I don't know how can i echo '`<pre>`' inside a foreach loop So i will get array as structured format.Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely;

```
@foreach ($getallDetials as $user)
  <pre>{{ print_r($user) }}</pre>
@endforeach
```

will work?

Comment: Excellent, please accept my answer when the system lets you :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@foreach ($getallDetials as $user)
  {{ $user['sname'] }}
@endforeach
```

`Note:` in laravel blade template every thing inside `{{ }}` will echo